# How do I mount (and repair) broken an Casper-rw file?

Tags: linux, mount

I red some tutorial, how to repair my casper-rw, there created by YUMI for Mint 19. File was created on USB, but now i copied it on HDD without r/w error.

```
$file casper-rw 
casper-rw: Linux rev 1.0 ext2 filesystem data (mounted or unclean), UUID=21054c3a-197b-774e-91ec-7f08ed0eb027, volume name "casper-rw" (errors) (large files)

$sudo mount casper-rw /media/cas
mount: /media/cas: can't read superblock on /dev/loop0.

$dumpe2fs casper-rw | grep superblock 
dumpe2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-1
  Backup superblock at 32768, Group descriptors at 32769-32769
  Backup superblock at 98304, Group descriptors at 98305-98305
  Backup superblock at 163840, Group descriptors at 163841-163841
  Backup superblock at 229376, Group descriptors at 229377-229377
  Backup superblock at 294912, Group descriptors at 294913-294913
  Backup superblock at 819200, Group descriptors at 819201-819201
  Backup superblock at 884736, Group descriptors at 884737-884737

$e2fsck -y -b 98304 casper-rw
  casper-rw was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
  Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
  Pass 2: Checking directory structure
  Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
  Pass 4: Checking reference counts
  Pass 5: Checking group summary information
  Free blocks count wrong for group #0 (31736, counted=6688).
  Fix? yes

  ...

  Directories count wrong for group #30 (0, counted=5).
  Fix? yes

  Free inodes count wrong (1047541, counted=1028864).
  Fix? yes


  casper-rw: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
  casper-rw: 18688/1047552 files (7.5% non-contiguous), 342826/1046784 blocks

$sudo mount -o sb=98304 casper-rw /media/cas
  mount: /media/cas: can't read superblock on /dev/loop0.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is BUG in the VirtualBox. Solution is mounting from "local" folders, nor from "shared" folders. i.e.:

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/17360?cversion=0&cnum_hist=1

Same issue with Guest OL7.5 on VBox 5.2.12 and GuestAdditions 5.2.12.

From a shared folder:

```
[root@OL7 OVM_3.4.x]# mount -o loop ovmm-3.4.5-installer-OracleLinux-b1919.iso /mnt
mount: /dev/loop0: can't read superblock
```

From a local folder:

```
[root@OL7 ovm]# mount -o loop ovmm-3.4.5-installer-OracleLinux-b1919.iso /mnt
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```